# How to convert hex string to bytes

Tags: python-3.x, hex

I have a hex string:

```
53 9B 33 3B 39 70 6D 14 90 28 CF E1 D9 D4 A4 07
```

I have the following code:

```
from binascii import unhexlify  
data = unhexlify(b'53 9B 33 3B 39 70 6D 14 90 28 CF E1 D9 D4 A4 07')
```

But it throws the following error
`binascii.Error: Odd-length string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have spaces in your argument.

```
from binascii import unhexlify    
data = unhexlify(b'539B333B39706D149028CFE1D9D4A407')
print(data)  # --> b'S\x9b3;9pm\x14\x90(\xcf\xe1\xd9\xd4\xa4\x07'
```